# How do i collect user input from many ViewPager slides at a button click in the last slide?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-activity, android-viewpager

**I'm trying not to overwhelm the user by collecting a lot of data in a single screen so I
 have used a 'Viewpager' with 3 XML layouts.** My button is in the last slide and I want to store all the data I've collected into Firestore. I'm having trouble getting the input from all slides all in one activity. What's the solution to my problem.

Here's my onClickListener code

```
           // Adding property details through onclick listener
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String location = Location.getText().toString().trim();
                        String surbab = Surbab.getText().toString().trim();
                        String city = City.getText().toString().trim();
                        String country = Country.getText().toString().trim();
                        String Name = name.getText().toString().trim();
                        Double Valuation = Double.valueOf(valuation.getText().toString().trim());
                        boolean Property_type = Boolean.parseBoolean(type.getText().toString().trim());
                        String No_of_units = number_of_units.getText().toString().trim();


                        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        if (!validateInputs(location, surbab, city, country, Name, String.valueOf(Valuation), No_of_units)) {

                            CollectionReference dbTenants = db.collection("Users");


                            Property property = new Property(
                                    location,
                                    surbab,
                                    city,
                                    country,
                                    Name,
                                    Valuation,
                                    Property_type,
                                    No_of_units

                            );
                            dbTenants.document(uid).collection("property").add(property)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                            Toast.makeText(PropertyActivity.this, "Tenant Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(PropertyActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

For the property class, I have this

```
package com.example.MyLandlordStudio;

public class Property {
    private String Locaation;
    private String Surbab;
    private String City;
    private String Country;
    private String name;
    private Double valuation;
    private boolean type;
    private String number_of_units;

    public Property() {

    }

    public Property(String locaation, String surbab, String city, String country, String name, Double valuation, boolean type, String number_of_units) {
        Locaation = locaation;
        Surbab = surbab;
        City = city;
        Country = country;
        this.name = name;
        this.valuation = valuation;
        this.type = type;
        this.number_of_units = number_of_units;
    }

    public String getLocaation() {
        return Locaation;
    }

    public String getSurbab() {
        return Surbab;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Double getValuation() {
        return valuation;
    }

    public boolean isType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getNumber_of_units() {
        return number_of_units;
    }
}
```

Here's a visual representation of what I mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R8Gj.png. When I press the green button I want to add all data from all slides into Firestore. Open the link for the image. Thanks in advance

Here's my adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SliderAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 3;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.address_slider_layout;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.description_slider_layout;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.confirm_slider_layout;
                break;

        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

@svi.data

Comment: Just curious where is the code that you use to extract data from view pager layouts?

Comment: That's exactly what I need to know. Because currently apart from using the normal `findViewById` to initialize my ``TextFields`` from different XML layouts and what I have done on the onClick, basically those ' getText ()` methods I have no idea what else I should do. @svi.data

Comment: show me the view pager adapter.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the page adapter @svi.data

Answer (score 0):

You can add one method in base activity/fragment which hold the object which contains this values.

for example BaseFragment is parent fragment of viewpager

BaseFragment.java

```
//create object of property
Property property=new Property();

//this method can be accessed in all the viewpager
public Property getPropertyValues(){
   return property;
}
```

ViewPager1.java (first viewpager)

```
//in onclick button or swipe add this
BaseFragment basefragment=(BaseFragment)ViewPager1.this.getParentFragment();
Property obj=basefragment.getPropertyValues();
obj.setLocation("your value");
...
...
 //same thing you have to do in viewpager2
```

viewpager3.java (last viewpager)

```
BaseFragment basefragment=(BaseFragment)ViewPager1.this.getParentFragment();
Property obj=basefragment.getPropertyValues();
String location=obj.getLocation();
...
...
...
//here you will get all the values
```